# Tenho esse código, como atualizar no sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

já tentei

```sql
$sql = " UPDATE biblioteca SET nome_usuario WHERE nome_usuario IN ( SELECT nome_usuario FROM ( SELECT  nome_usuario, COUNT(id_usuario) FROM orders WHERE nome_usuario )"
```

---

```
$sql = "UPDATE usuario(nome_usuario) VALUES ('$name') WHERE nome_usuario=".$_REQUEST["nome_usuario"];
```

---

```sql
$sql = "UPDATE usuario(nome_usuario) VALUES ('$name') WHERE nome_usuario= '$name'";
```

---

```php
<?php
    switch($_REQUEST["acao"]){
        case "editar":

            $sql = " UPDATE biblioteca SET nome_usuario WHERE nome_usuario IN ( SELECT nome_usuario FROM ( SELECT  nome_usuario, COUNT(id_usuario) FROM orders WHERE nome_usuario )"

             // SELECT * FROM biblioteca 
             // WHERE id_biblioteca=".$_REQUEST["id_biblioteca"];

            # $sql = "UPDATE usuario(nome_usuario) VALUES ('$name') WHERE nome_usuario= '$name'";
            # $sql = "UPDATE usuario(nome_usuario) VALUES ('$name') WHERE nome_usuario=".$_REQUEST["nome_usuario"];
            $res = $conn->query($sql);
            if($res==true){
                print "<br><div class='alert alert-success'>Usuário atualizado com sucesso!</div>";
            }else{
                print "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Não é possível atualizar o usuário.</div>";
            }
        break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: `SET nome_usuario WHERE` e onde está o valor para o "nome_usuario"? deveria ser algo como `SET nome_usuario='alguma coisa' WHERE`. Acho que não está entendendo bem como funciona o `update`, veja a documentação aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: Com todo respeito. Recomendo você fazer um curso de sql básico,tem muitos free pela internet que são bons. 
Tem um da softblue, muito bom (moderadores não sei se posso postar, se for proibido editem por favor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer atualizar o nome de um usuário, se for isso acredito que o código abaixo pode resolver:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];


$sql = "UPDATE users
SET name = '{$name}'
WHERE id = {$id}";

$res = $conn->query($sql);
```

Agora se você quer atualizar o usuário que está registrado na tabela biblioteca, você tem que fazer um relacionamento entre a tabela biblioteca e a tabela usuários.

Se você quer registrar um usuário na tabela biblioteca seria ideal haver uma coluna chamada user_id (chave estrangeira) que se refere a ao id da tabela de usuários.

Comment: Agora se você quer atualizar o usuário que está registrado na tabela biblioteca, você tem que fazer um relacionamento entre a tabela biblioteca e a tabela usuários. Como faço?

Comment: Pesquise por "criando uma chave estrangeira no MySQL", vai encontrar diversos tutoriais que irão te ajudar, é bem simples, no Youtube mesmo você encontra cursos de como fazer isso.